# How to Disable Page Caching in Trusted Web Activity App?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, twa

I created a Trusted Web Activity App for one of my friends.
Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grodudes.app
It's working absolutely fine but I am facing a small problem it is showing the cached pages even when the device is online and it causes problem like showing the user is logged out when moving to a different page even though he is logged in. Reloading the page fixes it.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Share your code. Link to compiled binary does not help

Comment: @Belegnar https://github.com/swapnilsen9/GroDudes.git 
This is the Repo. Please have a look and help me out.

Comment: A PWA loaded inside a Trusted Web Activity will behave exactly the same way, including using the same cache and storage as when the PWA is opened inside a regular browser tab. You should be able to reproduce this when testing inside the browser. The solution is likely to double-check the cache directives and the service-worker code.